# Insertar tildes en MySQL con POST desde Android a PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicación Android que realiza consultas con una base de datos alojada en un host con MySQL y cuando intento insertar texto que contiene acentos o algún carácter especial no lo inserta en la base de datos.

Tanto la app como la base de datos la tengo con cotejamiento `utf8` y `utf8_general_ci`.

Tengo entendido que hay que introducir una instrucción en el archivo PHP, pero he probado varias cosas y ninguna da resultado. En cambio si introduzco yo una palabra con acento desde la consola de phpmyadmin sí que me aparece en la aplicación.

```
<?php

$cod=$_REQUEST['cod'];
$tit=$_REQUEST['tit'];
$des=$_REQUEST['des'];

$cnx=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname;charset=utf8_general_ci","dbser","dbpass");

$res=$cnx->query("insert into noticias (id, titulo, descripcion) VALUES (0, '$tit', '$des')");
```

Éste es el fragmento Android:

```
public class First_fragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lstCursos;
    String recuperado;
    private ListView mylist;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab, container, false);
        //De este modo cambiamos el tema para cada uno de los layout
        getActivity().setTheme(R.style.Barra);

        Bundle recupera = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras ();
        if (recupera != null) {
            recuperado = recupera.getString ( "cod" );
        }

        Thread tr2 = new Thread () {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String resultado = enviarGET ( recuperado );
                getActivity().runOnUiThread ( new Runnable () {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ////////////////////////////////////////
                        cargarListView ( ArregloLista ( resultado ) );
                        ////////////////////////////////////////
                        // //////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                } );
            }
        };
        tr2.start ();
        return v;
    }

    public String enviarGET(String id){

        URL url = null;
        String linea = "";
        int respuesta = 0;
        StringBuilder resul = null;

        try {
            //url = new URL ("http://192.168.1.41/WebService/llenarnoticias.php?id="+id);
            url = new URL ("url");
            //Ahora enviamos el dato
            HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
            //Guardamos la respuesta en el entero, porque sera un uno o un cero
            //Esto es lo que devuelve la BD una vez hacemos la consulta
            respuesta = conection.getResponseCode ();
            //Inicializamos resul
            resul = new StringBuilder ();

            if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(in));

                while ((linea = reader.readLine ()) != null){
                    resul.append (linea);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return resul.toString ();
    }

    //Metodo que permite crear un arraylista para llena el listview
    public ArrayList<String> ArregloLista(String response){
        ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String> ();
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray (response);
            String texto = "";
            String texto2 = "";
            for(int i=0;i<json.length ();i++){
                texto = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("titulo");
                texto2 = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("descripcion");
                listado.add("\n" + texto + "\n\n" +texto2 + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return listado;
    }

    //Aquí es donde va TODA LA CHICHA
    public void cargarListView(ArrayList<String> datos){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
        lstCursos = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.listCursos);
        lstCursos.setAdapter (adaptador);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nada, sigue sin tragarse los acentos...

Comment: Nada, lo he probado todo y no hay manera. He revisado mil veces la base de datos por si tenía el fallo ahí, pero nada.

Comment: Mira esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1610475/2097224) revisa el `php.ini` y todo lo que pone en la respuesta

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código con el que desde Android intentas solicitar el dato a PHP? Ten en cuenta que internamente Android usa `UTF-16` para codificar textos contenidos en `String`, por lo que debes usar, por ejemplo, [`URLEncoder.encode(cadena, "utf-8");`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) para convertir el formato interno de Android a `UTF-8` antes de enviarlo al PHP. Tienes que gestionar correctamente cada uno de los pasos en los que se tratan los datos para que en alguno de ellos no se produzca un error de conversión o lectura.

Comment: Hola podrías probar cambiando el charset de tu conexión a tu base de datos, remplazando utf8_general_ci por utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar las funciones utf8_decode("string que quieres codificar para insertar en la bd") y utf8_encode("string de la bd que quieres descodificar para usar en java").

```
$tit=utf8_encode($_REQUEST['tit']);
$des=utf8_encode($_REQUEST['des']);
```

Comment: Pero donde? En el archivo php o en el código java?

Comment: En el php cuando pides los datos, luego en java ya te llegan bien codificados. Seguramente tengas que rehacer el objeto que devuelves para tener el resultado que deseas.

Comment: Podrías indicarme en el php como irían por favor? Las variable que quiero decodificar son tit y des

Comment: $tit=utf8_encode($_REQUEST['tit']);
$des=utf8_encode($_REQUEST['des']);

Comment: Sigue sin dejarme introducir acentos. Si lo pongo sin acentos sí que se lo traga, pero con acentos no.

Comment: prueba con decode y dime... es que se que valen para eso pero no tengo muy claro cual sirve para que cosa...

Comment: Ya he probado con los dos...y ha compilado y funciona y todo, pero sin acentos.

Comment: los datos los pides desde java o desde php?

Comment: Los pido a la bd desde php, de todos modos ahora pongo la clase .java por si la quereis ver.

Comment: cuando los pide tambien tienes que usar el utf8_encode

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrías probar cambiando el charset de tu conexión a tu base de datos, remplazando utf8_general_ci por utf8mb4
Tu conexión a tu DB:

```
$cod=$_REQUEST['cod'];
$tit=$_REQUEST['tit'];
$des=$_REQUEST['des'];

$cnx = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname;charset=utf8mb4","dbser","dbpass");

$res = $cnx->query("insert into noticias (id, titulo, descripcion) VALUES (0, '$tit', '$des')");
```

Cotejamiento en tu base de datos y tablas:

```
utf8mb4_general_ci
```

A mi me funciona bien, espero ayudarte.